# Set the value of the Django 2 Admin Autocomplete widget using jQuery

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to add some custom logic with jQuery to a django admin view. I want to change the value of some select fields on my tabular inline fields when the value the "formula" Select Input Change.

[image]

I've tried the following code, but the django admin autocomplete values does not change.

```
    rowNumber = 0
    var ingredientInput = $('#id_formulaexplosioningredient_set-' + rowNumber + '-ingredient');
    // console.log('aaa', ingredient, rowNumber, ingredientInput, );
    console.log('select', ingredientInput.select2());
    console.log('djangoAdminSelect2', ingredientInput.djangoAdminSelect2());
    ingredientInput.djangoAdminSelect2().val(ingredient.ingredient.id.toString()).trigger('change');
    ingredientInput.select2().val(ingredient.ingredient.id.toString()).trigger('change');
    ingredientInput.val(ingredient.ingredient.id.toString()).trigger('change');
```

As you can see I tried 3 ways, with the val() of the element. The val() of the select2 plugin and the val() of the djangoAmindSelect2() plugin.

Can anyone help me out and show me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. The issue was that the select uses ajax to fetch the data so I had to first create option and then select it with the select2:select event. I hope this helps someone.

```
 var newOption = new Option(ingredient.ingredient.name, ingredient.ingredient.id, true, true);
 ingredientInput.append(newOption).trigger('change');
 // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
 ingredientInput.trigger({
      type: 'select2:select',
      params: {
      data: {
        text: ingredient.ingredient.name,
        id: ingredient.ingredient.id.toString(),
      }
    }
 });
```